# bass.dll peak level meter

Tags: c++, qt, bass.dll

получаю из канала пиковые значения.

```
BASS_ChannelGetLevelEx(chan, levels, 0.02, BASS_LEVEL_STEREO    );
```

данную функцию вызываю в цикле с той же частотой
void Thread::run()
{

```
while(!m_abort)
{

    emit SetLevels();
    QThread::msleep(20);
}
```

}

рисуется это дело через QPainter

вот что выходит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

бегает что дурное, скачки резкие делает, а должно быть плавненько
уже задолбался подгонять.

наверно что-то не так сделал.

Comment: В Qt 5.7 включены графики. Анамация там из коробки поддержаивается. Может лучше этим воспользоваться, нежели чем своё делать? Впрочем, у Вас тут какой-нибудь `QVariantAnimation` для плавности вполне подойдёт.

Comment: у меня почему то никогда не работает регистрирование типов

Comment: qRegisterAnimationInterpolator<QColor>(myColorInterpolator);
выдает

Comment: ошибка: specializing member '::qRegisterAnimationInterpolator<QColor>' requires 'template<>' syntax
 qRegisterAnimationInterpolator<QColor>(myColorInterpolator);
 ^

Comment: пример прямо из доки взял

Comment: Ну вообще странно, всё работает, проверил. Вы где хоть размещается регистрируемую функцию `myColorInterpolator` и собственно сам вызов регистрации `qRegisterAnimationInterpolator`?

Comment: да везде пробовал, в шапке, после инклюдов в cpp , в конструкторе пробовал. а еще проделывал эти действия на двух разных системах: вин и линукс

Comment: вот создал новый проект , вписал туда регистрацию нового типа http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/537367/qregisteranimationinterpolatorqcolormycolorinterpolator-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD

Comment: не подскажете как QVariantAnimation прицепить к лайоуту или виджету? или что с ним вобще делать после создания?  дока просто мега подробная по нему...

Comment: Ну он на самом деле промежуточный класс для кастомных типов данных, которые надо анимировать. Если у Вас один из простых (`int`, `double` и т.п.) или тот же `QColor`, то рекомендую воспользоваться `QPropertyAnimation`. Он является наследником `QVariantAnimation` и всё, что надо для запуска анимации уже в себе содержит. Создайте свой объект или виджет, добавьте в него [свойство](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html), которое хотите анимировать, ну а уже саму анимацию включайте через `QPropertyAnimation` (в доке к этому классу пример имеется).

Comment: ну с ним я пол дня ковырялся. пробовал изменять maximumHeight, так он почему то изменяет с обоих сторон. это бы подошло для wave-form. но у меня к сожалению не это. что-то похожее получилось сделать изменяя "geometry" но в итоге получилось все точно так же как и с QPainter'ом. Вобщем я еще заморочился, разобрал исходник spectrum из примеров bass, там рисовался уровень на 20 вроди столбцов, было красиво, как только я сделал 2(там просто в цикле они рисовались) получилось точно как у меня, даже хуже.  А тот пример написан на голом c++ без qt