# qRegisterAnimationInterpolator<QColor>(myColorInterpolator); выдает ошибку что не так?

Tags: qt

```
ошибка: specializing member '::qRegisterAnimationInterpolator<QColor>' requires 'template<>' syntax
```

mainwndow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QLinearGradient>
#include <QVariantAnimation>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>


QVariant myColorInterpolator(const QColor &start, const QColor &end, qreal progress)
{
    return QColor(Qt::red);
}

qRegisterAnimationInterpolator<QColor>(myColorInterpolator); // ЭТО ВЫЗЫВАЕТ ОШИБКУ

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QLinearGradient>
#include <QVariantAnimation>


namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    QVariant myColorInterpolator(const QColor &start, const QColor &end, qreal progress);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

даже проще:

```
typedef int x;
qRegisterMetaType<int>("x"); // выдает ту же ошибку.
```

Comment: Вызовы функций, начинающихся с `qRegister...` должны быть внутри методов классов или других собственных функций.

Comment: ну простейший пример с int работает в другой функции, а регистрация анимации выдает

Comment: ошибка: no matching function for call to 'QVariant::QVariant(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'

Comment: Попробуйте добавить заголовочник `QColor`. Вообще, так то нонсенс, не встречался никогда с проблемами при регистрации.

Comment: Блин так QVariant не надо было регистрировать в шапке

Comment: С Вашего последнего комментария возникает неопределённость, решили ли Вы проблему?

Comment: да, решил. вызвал регистрацию в  функции и убрал QVariant myColorInterpolator(...  из шапки

Comment: Зачем вы посреди файла написали `qRegisterAnimationInterpolator<QColor>(myColorInterpolator);` и что это по вашему должно значить? Это бессмысленный синтаксис. Ничего подобного в С++ нет.

Answer (score 1):

Автор вопроса самостоятельно решил проблему. Изъял из заголовка класса объявление метода `myColorInterpolator()`, а вызов регистрации стал производить в теле функции.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/89730)

Comment: @MaxZS , Вы хотя бы прочитали, что написано, а также посмотрели, что ответ отмечен как общий.